# Programmatically Adding an Option with Extra Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multi-select element with an ajax data source. I need to automatically populate my select2 with preselected options on load. I followed the instructions [in the docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2) to populate the options and this works correctly. However, it does not seem to add the extra data that I pass in - it only has the ID and text.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// create the option and append to Select2
let option = new Option('value', 'id', true, true);
$('#mySelect2').append(option).trigger('change');

// manually trigger the `select2:select` event; pass all data
let data = {
    id: 'id',
    text: 'value',
    anotherId: 'anotherID',
    moreData: 'moreData'
};
$('#mySelect2').trigger({
    type: 'select2:select',
    params: {
        data: data
    }
});
```

Yet when I try accessing the selected elements via `$('#mySelect2').select2('data')`, the extra attributes (anotherId, moreData) are not there. How can I pass in the extra data so that it mimics what happens when the user actually chooses an option from the dropdown? (Then the extra data attributes show up when calling `select2('data')`.)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a straightforward way to do it, so I added code to manually hack it (forcefully add it to the select2 data).

```
// create the option and append to Select2
let option = new Option('value', 'id', true, true);
$('#mySelect2').append(option).trigger('change');

let data = {
    id: 'id',
    anotherId: 'anotherID',
    moreData: 'moreData'
};

// modify the added option manually - add extra data attributes (in addition to id and text)
let $current_option_data = $(this).select2('data').find(function (currentOption) {
    return currentOption.id == data['id']
});
if ($current_option_data) {
    $current_option_data['anotherId'] = e.params.data['anotherId'];
    $current_option_data['moreData'] = e.params.data['moreData'];
}

// manually trigger the `select2:select` event
$('#mySelect2').trigger({
    type: 'select2:select'
});
```